# Input Multiple Data Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I would like to ask for help to check my script below. Because when I tried to submit my form with multiple input field it only results in one data, whereas, there should be two data entered into the database.

So, which part of my script is wrong?

**Controller**

```
public function add() {
    // ... some script before 'else' ...
    } else {

        $post = $this->input->post();
        $result = array();
        $total_input = count($post['input_acc_code']);
        foreach ($post['input_acc_code'] as $key => $value) {
            $result[] = array(
                'trans_type' => 'journal',
                'form_type' => NULL,
                'acc_code' => $post['input_acc_code'][$key],
                'acc_type_id' => $post['input_acc_type_id'][$key],
                'refference' => '',
                'customer_ID' => NULL,
                'acc_side' => '',
                'debet' => $post['input_debet'][$key],
                'credit' => $post['input_credit'][$key],
                'summary' => $post['input_note'][$key],
                'files' => NULL,
                'create_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now"))
                );
            if($this->model_transaction->savedata('fi_acc_journal', $result) == TRUE) {

               $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Success');
               redirect(base_url().'admin/transaction');
            } else {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Failed');
               redirect(base_url().'admin/transaction');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function savedata($table, $data = array()) {
    $this->db->insert_batch($table, $data);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

**View**

```
<?php $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
echo form_open_multipart(base_url().$this->session->userdata('user_status').'/transaction/add', $attributes);?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 panel-form-input">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="input_datetime" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tanggal Transaksi</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="input-date form-control" name="input_datetime[]" id="input-date">
                <?php echo form_error('input_datetime');?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 panel-form-input">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-unbordered">
                    <thead>
                        <th class="col-25">Account</th>
                        <th class="col-5">Account Type</th>
                        <th class="col-35">Notes</th>
                        <th class="col-15">Debet</th>
                        <th class="col-15">Credit</th>
                        <th class="col-5"></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        // First Input Field Form Table

                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-25">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <select class="select-transaction input-group-sm form-control" name="input_acc_code[]" id="acc_code_1">
                                        <?php if ($account_list != NULL): ?>
                                            <option>— Choose Account Number —</option>
                                            <?php foreach ($account_list as $value): ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $value->acc_code;?>"><?php echo $value->acc_name;?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                            <?php else:?>
                                            <option>— No Data —</option>
                                        <?php endif;?>
                                        </select>
                                        <?php echo form_error('input_acc_code[]');?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-5">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input_acc_type_id[]" id="acc_type_id_1">
                                        <?php echo form_error('input_acc_type_id[]');?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-35">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input_note[]">
                                        <?php echo form_error('input_note[]');?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-15">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input_debet[]">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-15">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input_credit[]">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-5"></td>
                        </tr>

                        // Second Input Field Form Table

                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-25">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <select class="select-transaction input-group-sm form-control" name="input_acc_code[]" id="acc_code_1">
                                        <?php if ($account_list != NULL): ?>
                                            <option>— Choose Account Number —</option>
                                            <?php foreach ($account_list as $value): ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $value->acc_code;?>"><?php echo $value->acc_name;?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                            <?php else:?>
                                            <option>— No Data —</option>
                                        <?php endif;?>
                                        </select>
                                        <?php echo form_error('input_acc_code[]');?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-5">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input_acc_type_id[]" id="acc_type_id_1">
                                        <?php echo form_error('input_acc_type_id[]');?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-35">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input_note[]">
                                        <?php echo form_error('input_note[]');?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-15">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input_debet[]">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-15">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input_credit[]">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-5"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="menu-bar">
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="submit">Save</input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Thank you for your help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `insert_batch` related model call out of the foreach, as otherwise you could just run a straight insert there. First you are building the queries to insert, then after the foreach you insert the multidimensional array!

```
public function add()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();
    $result = array();
    $total_input = count($post['input_acc_code']);
    foreach ($post['input_acc_code'] as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = array(
            'trans_type'  => 'journal',
            'form_type'   => NULL,
            'acc_code'    => $post['input_acc_code'][$key],
            'acc_type_id' => $post['input_acc_type_id'][$key],
            'refference'  => '',
            'customer_ID' => NULL,
            'acc_side'    => '',
            'debet'       => $post['input_debet'][$key],
            'credit'      => $post['input_credit'][$key],
            'summary'     => $post['input_note'][$key],
            'files'       => NULL,
            'create_at'   => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now"))
        );
    }        
    if ($this->model_transaction->savedata('fi_acc_journal', $result) == TRUE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Success');
        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/transaction');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Failed');
        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/transaction');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Alex. It's work now. Sorry my bad not to check that part of foreach =)

Comment: You also don't have to do strtotime in your date function. It will do that automatically using time() if the second date parameter is left blank

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I do this to prevent errors when someone entering data. i used jquery datepicker but in my database (phpmyadmin) using datetime format.